# Problem with quotation marks on Win 10 computer

Tags: r

I am having a problem with the quotation marks on a win 10 computer. I did not used to have this problem before.

e.g.

When I type:

```
install.packages(“abn”)
```

This gives an error message:

> Error: unexpected input in "install.packages(“"

The correct typing would be:

```
install.packages("abn")
```

but how do I get this easily on a windows 10 keyboard?

Comment: You can workaround with using `install.packages('abn')`. Also check the keyboard settings and share some more informations with us. Which editor are you using etc.

Comment: This is most likely not keyboard related but it looks like the editor you are using uses smart quotation marks. This happens for example in word or outlook. If you use a normal development environment this should not be happening. What locale is your keyboard?

Comment: That depends on your Keyboard Layout / Input Language - check your currently selected in the Windows Control Center (Taskbar).

Comment: Where you are typing this code? Are you using RStudio? Are you using the R GUI? Are you typing at the R console or in a script editor window?

Comment: I am typing this code in Office but you are right, in RGUI it is fine. Thanks for your help.